# How to detect which stored procedures UPDATE or INSERT into a certain TABLE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have many SQL files that represent stored procedures, these stored procedures are **encrypted** in the Database.

Is there any tool that allows me to detect which of these stored procedures UPDATE or INSERT into a certain TABLE?

Maybe a NOTEPAD++ regular expression could help me to achieve this?

Comment: So do the files contain the encrypted contents or not?

Comment: @AaronBertrand the files are PLAIN TEXT and are kept in order to be able to mantain the stored procedures

Comment: One idea then would be to temporarily create them, unencrypted, in a dummy database somewhere, then you could parse them with existing metadata functionality (e.g. `sys.sql_modules`) instead of seeking some external solution.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I had the same idea about the dummy database, but how do i get the  stored procedures that UPDATE and INSERT not all the ones that use the table ?

Comment: Well will likely lead to false positives but you could narrow your search to `WHERE UPPER(definition) LIKE '%UPDATE%tablename%'` etc.

Answer (score 11):

To start, there is no way to derive information from a stored procedure definition or its metadata that will tell you, without any doubt, that this procedure performs an insert or an update on a specific table. SQL Server just doesn't maintain that type of info. RegEx might get you close, but you're relying on fallible string patterns.

Now, in your specific case, you have the added complication of encryption. There are tools out there that can decrypt stored procedure definitions, and you can search for them (there is an ethical reason why I won't hand those to you here).

In the meantime, since you have the unencrypted versions in text files, I suggest you use those to create the procedures, temporarily, in a dummy database, without encryption (you'll have to do some kind of search and replace to remove this option from the procedure declaration). Then you can use the built-in metadata (such as `OBJECT_DEFINITION()` or `sys.sql_modules`) to parse the text just like you would with the text files. Once the procedures are created (again, unencrypted), you can do something like this to find stored procedures which use the `UPDATE` keyword prior to mentioning your table name:

```
SELECT s.name, p.name, m.definition
  FROM sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN sys.procedures AS p
  ON s.[schema_id] = p.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
  ON p.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
  WHERE UPPER(m.definition) LIKE N'%UPDATE%TABLENAME%';
```

And change that up (or add an `OR`) to handle `INSERT`.

Now, this can lead to a lot of false positives:

- updates one table then selects from your table of interest
- has an update in a comment
- `tablename` is actually contained in other, longer object names (one of the reasons I prefer `Customers` over `Customer`, for example)

However, it should narrow down the list so that the manual work you have to do, in order to be confident you've identified the right set of procedures, is minimized. No automated string parsing will get you there 100% for many of the same "false positive" reasons. And don't forget that you may have procedures that use dynamic SQL and build the table name or the entire command from input variables - no string parsing is going to find those, either.

Comment: Aaron your solution required to create a dummy database so I decided to used NOTEPAD++ with the regular expresions "UPDATE.*ORDERS" and a normal seach string of "INSERT INTO ORDERS" both using the SEARCH IN FILES option

Comment: @Mauricio ok, for future reference creating a database isn't that hard `CREATE DATABASE dummy` and could be useful for other things (e.g. just having your schema and *unencrypted* procedures available for testing/debugging etc). Even more powerful might be considering actual source control.

Comment: Creation of the database is fast but the time to remove the "with encription", run all the stored procedures it's a time consuming task, so I decided to spend that time on actually solving my problem and of course ACTUAL SOURCE CONTROL over the procedures would help any tool that you recommend for that or you mean TFS con the SQL files ? I already have that one

Comment: @Mauricio well, ok, but again I was saying that you could use the database containing these unencrypted versions of the procedures (and `WITH ENCRYPTION` should be pretty trivial to search/replace) for other purposes than just this specific operation. As for which source control platform to use, I don't really have any useful recommendations. I've heard good things about RedGate's but if you already have TFS... the important part is establishing and enforcing the process.

Comment: is not trivial when all the stored procedures are scattered in different VERSION folders and not centralized

Comment: @Mauricio that seems like a different problem, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
select distinct o.name, o.type_desc, dep.is_updated
FROM sys.sql_modules   m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.sql_dependencies dep ON m.object_id = dep.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON dep.referenced_major_id = col.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab ON tab.object_id = col.object_id
WHERE tab.name = 'BasketOrderForm'
and is_updated = 1
ORDER BY O.name
```

Here is the Result:

```
Name                                    type_desc               is_updated
procBasketHelperMergeBasketOrderForms   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE    1   
procListImport_Baskets                  SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE    1   
procListTransferInsertBasketOrderForm   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE    1   
procTS360SubmitBasket                   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE    1   
procTS360TransferBasketToUsers          SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE    1   
tdBasketLineItems                       SQL_TRIGGER             1   
tuBasketOrderForm                       SQL_TRIGGER             1
```

Comment: I'd like to know why this was downvoted twice. Downvotes without a reason are damaging. This is a good path to a solution. The encryption is not handled, but that is a comment, not a downvote. What's the deal?

Comment: For those coming late to the party like me, `sql_dependencies` has been deprecated as of 2016 in favor of `sql_expression_dependecies`. details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: It's disappointing that sql_expression_dependencies does not provide an is_updated column similarly to the sql_dependencies. However, anecdotally, I have seen inaccuracies using the original sql_dependencies -> is_updated column. Perhaps this is why they deprecated it.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) by redgate is a tool that makes this very easy. It makes searches for dependencies (via searches for individual elements such as tables, columns, stored procs, etc...) trivial, even across databases. Best of all, it's free for commercial use.

Comment: Does it parse encrypted procedures?

Comment: Aaron y Michael its only showing results for some UNENCRYPTED stored procedures that I have. So it does not help

Comment: I know I'm late to the game with this reply but just to clarify, their website says it is free (not specifically for non-commercial use) and I can't see any purchasing/licensing options